# How to Cross-Reference/Verify Asp.Net website pages

Tags: asp.net

I've inherited an Asp.Net website (VS/VB 2008 Express). There are many files which are copies of other files (previous developers would copy a code-behind page and rename it to make changes, so Page.aspx would have PageUpdateA.aspx.vb as its code-behind page, but Page.aspx.vb would still exist).

Is there a way to cross reference the site pages/files to verify/validate the pages, primarily to find unused pages?

I need a tool that will work from the source code, using a crawler to crawl the site itself won't work.

I have access to all versions of VS 2008 (and 2010/2012).